# How to add the snap to the facebook status from a 3rd party app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am not able add the thumbnail in the facebook update, using javascrit. But I dont know how to add the snap or add thumbnil, the facebook bot is not picking any pic fro the app, its a ruby on rails app actually.

I am using simple technique I have not created any app or no api key and such things.

I how do I get the thumbnils ?

Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question... You have a Rails app and a "Like" button and when you press the like button there is no thumbnail of the web page in your facebook status?

If that's the case you shoud take a look to the Open Graph Protocol: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

You must use some tags in your page to provide Facebook with information about your website and one of the tags is for the image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```